# How to know the recipients received mails and reading mails

Tags: php, mysql

In my project I have to send an email. So far it is working properly. But I need to know how many recipients have received email and how many of them have read it.

Answer (score 0):

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Figuring_out_whether_the_recipient_read_your_message

Basic jist of it is send a very small image. If the user downloads it and the server logs it, you've just confirmed that they've at least opened the message